# Are some functionalities of RevitPythonWrapper out of date?

Tags: pyrevit

I'd like to use rpw (https://github.com/gtalarico/revitpythonwrapper) with pyRevit and RPS in Revit 2018. I have installed rpw from github beginning of this month so I can use it with RPS, and now trying to use some dialogs functionalities, like the "Alert" one. But I got some errors when calling rpw within pyRevit scripts, for instance saying that the "header" argument in Alert isn't expected, or error when trying to import rpw.ui.forms.CommandLink.

But, for instance, if I use the same "Alert" command, with the 'header' argument from within RPS, it works perfectly fine. The CommandLink import works fine as well.

Why? (using pyRevit v4.4:9c6ae17)

Thanks!

Arnaud.

Answer (score 1):

Ok indeed the rpw code shipped with pyRevit is different. Should have looked into it before ;)

Comment: Arnaud you are correct.

You can override the rpw version   by adding a path to a local copy of rpw on pyrevits settings